# Is there a format independent way to deal with archives on the JVM?

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, archive

I'm interested in dealing with archive contents in a similar way to dealing with Images through the awt.imageio api: Just get them as a file and see if you know how to decode them.

Obviously, there's the jar apis but I believe they only work with zip formats.

End use is Clojure code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that some of the types you can handle through [Apache Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) library. I think, that you can also make a close look to [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org) library, that extracts text and metadata from different file types, and as I remember, that they want to extend Apache Compress with more archive types (look onto patches in the JIRA)

Comment: Also check out [tebeka/digest](https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/clj-digest/src) as a clojure abstraction over Apache Compress.